# Learn python the hard way, exercise 6.

Tags: python

I searched the site but it seems like this exercise from the book Learn Python the Hard way wasn't covered in previous questions.

I have this exercise:

1)Find all the places where a string is put inside a string. There are four places.
2)Are you sure there's only four places? How do you know? Maybe I like lying.

```
x = "There are %d types of people." % 10
binary = "binary"
do_not = "don't"
y = "Those who know %s and those who %s." % (binary, do_not) #two strings inside a string, count is 2

print x
print y

print "I said: %r." % x #here, count is 3
print "I also said: '%s'." % y #here, count is 4

hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %r"

print joke_evaluation % hilarious

w = "This is the left side of..."
e = "a string with a right side."

print w + e
```

I tried to solve it and commented the lines where I found a string inside a string(found4). But, the author's second questions makes me worry I haven't found all. Have I miss something? If yes, can you please tell me what?

Comment: Dive Into Python is for experienced programmers (the first example is code to make an "ODBC helper"), Learn Python the Hard Way is to introduce programming to an audience that needs to be introduced to the concept of strings, if, etc. So there are hardly comparable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you interpret "putting a string inside a string" as "using a format character with a string argument", you correctly identified all four occurrences. It may be more helpful to put away the useless instructions and explain what happens. For more information, have a look at the [offical documentation for formatting characters](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). I'll try to include some *helpful* exercises without trick questions.

```
x = "There are %d types of people." % 10
```

`%d` is the formatting character for a `Signed integer decimal` (what most people think of when hearing a "number"). 10 is expressed in decimal and inserted into the string, resulting in the string `There are 10 types of people.`.

*Excercise*: What would `"7+6: %d" % (7+6)` result in? Test it in your Python shell.
*Excercise*: What would `"0x12: %d" % 0x12` result in? Test it in your Python shell.
Hint: A prefix of `0x` means the following number is [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), i.e. base 16 instead of 10.

```
binary = "binary"
do_not = "don't"
y = "Those who know %s and those who %s." % (binary, do_not)
```

`%s` inserts the string representation of a value. This example goes to show that if there is more than one `%d`, `%s` or so in a format string, we need to give that number of arguments, in a *tuple* or *list*. The difference between a tuple (round, braces) and a list [square, braces] is that a tuple is immutable(i.e. can't be changed), but a list can.

*Excercise*: Given the tuple `x = ('world', 'Hello')`, construct a tuple `y` with the correct order of words. [Dive Into Python's introduction of tuples](http://diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/tuples.html) will help you understand the basics of tuples.

```
print "I said: %r." % x
```

`%r` is the *representation* of a value, ideally something you could enter into a Python shell. You can get the same representation with the [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) function. For example, `repr("a") == "'a'"`, whereas `str(a) == "a"`. For most types except string, the result of `repr` and `str` (or `%r` and `%s` in format strings) is the same.

```
print w + e
```

This *concatenates* two strings (i.e. puts one after the other). Note that the `+` means something else (addition) if both arguments are numbers.

*Excercise*: What is the result of `"3" + "4"`? Test it in your Python shell.
*Excercise*: Given `x = "3"; y = "4"`, print out the sum 7 ([Hint](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int)).

Comment: First of all thank you so very much for writing me such a detailed 
response. Another user(who's message is gone, don't know why) wrote in his response that the 5ft string inside a string is at %hilarious. 

You said: "If you interpret "putting a string inside a string" as "using the format character with a string argument", you correctly identified all four occurrences." %r is also a string argument, isn't the line with %hilarious also a string inside a string? It's connected with the string in joke_evaluation.

Comment: @0101amt With string argument I meant the values *after* `%`, no matter what format character (`%d`, `%s`, `%r`) is being used. The argument of `joke_evaluation` is a boolean (a truth value). Sorry, just saw that I left that out in the answer, but that's because booleans(Named after [George Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole)) are simple: They're either `False` or `True`. Unsurprisingly, `"%r" % False` is just `"False"`.